# Laravel HomePage is loading too slow (30s)

Tags: php, loading, laravel-8

I'm doing social website. But i have a problem about load homepage so slow (30-40s). Can i fix something? Help me, Please.
**This is HomeController**

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $category_post = Category::orderBy('category_id', 'DESC')->get();
        $post2 = Post::orderBy('tbl_post.created_at','DESC')->paginate(5);
        
        return view('student.page.home')->with(compact('category_post','post2'));
}
```

**1 part of my foreach**

```
@foreach($post2 as $key => $post_info)
<p style="font-size: 20px;" class="widget-box-status-text">{{$post_info->post_title}}</p>
<br>
<p style="white-space: pre-line;" class="read-more widget-box-status-text">{{$post_info->post_content}}</p>
<div class="tag-list">
 <a class="tag-item secondary" style="font-size: 16px" href="{{url('/quest-category/'.$post_info->category_id)}}">{{$post_info->category->category_name}}</a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = FALSE;
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_student_name', 'post_student_email', 'post_title', 'category_id', 'post_content', 'created_at'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';
    protected $table = 'tbl_post';

    public function student(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Student','student_id');
    }
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are facing the `n + 1` problem. [Eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) might help you here.

Comment: @holymoof is correct regarding the `n+1` issue, but 30 seconds is still excessive for 5 posts, each with a 1:1 category relationship. Do you have xdebug enabled? That can slow things down.

Comment: as @holymoof mention, you should try to preload category in the posts, like `Post::orderBy('tbl_post.created_at','DESC')->with('category')->paginate(5);` but this is no where nead slow to cause 30s of delay... probably your server has some problem

Comment: @holymoof manythanks, i'll try this

Comment: @StephenLewis I'm not Xdebug enable

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I also thought it was the server, but it's not

Comment: @TienDatTr how are you running your server? if the database is not "near" to your server, probably that will cause this delay (for example the server in local but the DB on the VPS that you are using to publish your website)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia currently i am running on localhost and my database it is on 1 remotemysql.com website, but when i deploy on heroku, it's still slow

Comment: @TienDatTr you have to deploy the db also on heroku, for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can optimize your eloquent query using Eager Loading :

```
$post2 = Post::with('category')->orderBy('tbl_post.created_at','DESC')->paginate(5);
```

It also depends on many other things, for example, Network connection, Cache, CSS, and JS file, loaded asset, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried it and it went down to 20s